# Tell cmake take another version of the package

Tags: macos, cmake, homebrew

I have OpenCV and OpenCV3 installed via Homebrew.

OpenCV is linked and can be reached by cmake via

```
/usr/local/share/OpenCV
```

OpenCV3 is not linked and is located here

```
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.0.0
```

I have this `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( DisplayImage )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp )
target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

When I run `cmake`, it uses the first version of OpenCV.
How can I tell `cmake` to use the second package?

**UPDATE:**

I tried to specify

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.0.0/share/OpenCV")
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
```

and

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.0.0/share/")
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
```

But in the `CMakeCache.txt` I still see this:

```
OpenCV_CONFIG_PATH:FILEPATH=/usr/local/share/OpenCV
```

Which again is not what I need..

Thank you.

Comment: `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` specifies path to the cmake script, which is used for finding package. Instead of setting this variable, you should set OpenCV-related variables. The only setup variable, described in `FindOpenCV.cmake`, is `OpenCV_DIR`. Try to set it to `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.0.0`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I don't have the `FindOpenCV.cmake` file.. Where is it on your filesystem?

Comment: No needs to modify that file, just set variable in your CMakeLists.txt file, like you tried with `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` one.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of options.

**Option 1**

Use:

```
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/opencv3  cmake ...
```

**Option 2**

Replace

```
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
```

with

```
find_package(OpenCV HINTS /usr/local/opt/opencv3 /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3 REQUIRED)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to unlink opencv and link opencv3:

```
> readlink /usr/local/share/OpenCV
  ../Cellar/opencv/2.4.11_2/share/OpenCV
> brew unlink opencv
> brew link opencv3 --force
> readlink /usr/local/share/OpenCV
  ../Cellar/opencv3/3.0.0/share/OpenCV
```

Otherwise, you probably want to set the appropriate variable for CMake: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it works. But I want to achieve this without unlinking/linking..